# react.js: Create resource with redux-form, rest api and async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I'm trying to create new resource with redux form and REST api.

I dispatch `createPost` action and I want to check if the post was succeeded before continue.

```
const handleFormSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {
    dispatch(createPost(values));
    //I want to check here if post was succeeded.
    //if status = 200 this.props.history.push('/');
}


export function createPost(values) {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    let request;
    try {
      request = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts`, values)
    } catch(err) {
      request = { err };
    }
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_POST,
      payload: request
    })    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a promise, something like this :

```
export function createPost(values) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return new Promise( async function(resolve, reject){
      let request;
      try {
        request = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts`, values)
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: request
      }) 
      resolve(request)
    })
  }   
}

   const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(createPost(values))
        .then( res => {
          // do yoour stuff on succes
        } )
        .catch(err => {
          // stuff on err
        }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As seeing your codes, I don't think you need to use promise.
Please try like following:

```html
const getAction = (values) => (dispatch) => {
  return axios
          .post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts`, values)
          .then(
            () => {
              dispatch({
                type: CREATE_POST,
                payload: request
              })
            },
            () => {
              throw new SubmissionError({
                _error: 'Failed'
              });
            }
           );
};

const handleSubmit = (values) => {
  return dispatch(getAction(values));
};
```